# Updating data I got via form in Express using Postgres and HTML

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I trying to update data in my table in Node. I'm trying to use  `router.put` to update category row of my table.

I know how to update stuff with `router.post` but it has to refresh the whole page. I want to use `router.put` to update the data immediately.

Express JS code:

```js
router.put('/restaurants',function (req,res,next){
    pool.connect(function(err,client){
        if(err){
            console.info("Error");
        } else{
            client.query('UPDATE restaurant SET category = $1 WHERE name = $2;',[req.body.category,req.body.restaurant],function(err,result){
                if(!err){
                    res.send("Successful");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML form:

```html
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="category">Choose restaurant:</label>
        <select name="restaurant">
            <%for(let i=0;i<query.length;++i){%>
                <option><%=query[i].name%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>
        <label for="category">Change category:</label>
        <input type="text" name="category">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

What do I need to add so after the query it automatically updates the data on the page? I am getting ERROR 404 at the moment with the current code.

Comment: You need to change form's method to PUT, that would make it update again, but its just more semantically correct, it would still reload the page. If you are looking for sending data without updating the page, you have to handle sending the data asynchronously in javascript using fetch

Comment: @HaythemFarhat After I added that, the only thing is that it doesn't give me 404 error and it adds stuff to url -> `?restoran=U2+Pizzerija&kategorija=Test`
Nothing updates. Im pretty sure I have to use POST to update it with router.get